# List of all the Firefox and Chrome extensions

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Does anyone know how I can get to a list of all the extensions of Firefox and Chrome?
I do not want an addon what I can use to dump all of my extensions, I want all the available  extensions for Firefox and for Chrome.
What data do I want, preferably the name of the application and the name of the developer.

Comment: are you looking at installed extensions on user browser or available extensions on web?

Comment: @Sudarshan I would like to have all the available extensions for the google chrome and Firefox store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is an organized list of all the extensions for either browsers since their extensions are as numerous as they are. So, the only answer I have is to check out their extension pages(see below).

Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions

Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/extensions/?sort=featured